# access metro style app from standart windows side

Tags: .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing for Windows 8 Single language, Our device(tablet) have Standart Windows 8 and Metro Style together. I'm developing on Windows side and I want to access the MetroStyle side to start an application(camera vb.). Can I access  camera ? How ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Metro Apps run in isolation, so you can't communicate with them from inside windows and access their data including data they get from WebCam.
But they can call WebServices and WCF so you must be able to connect to let's say a WCF service listening on your windows application. You probably need to poll that service for commands like 'start webcam'